# Tomcat not using JAXB for JSON marshalling correctly?

Tags: json, rest, tomcat, jaxb, grizzly

I'm working on a RESTful Web-service using Jersey v1.9.1. Some methods return JSON. When I want to **Debug** my application I start within a grizzly server, otherwise for **production** I build a war file and place it in a TomCat v7 installation. My projects are all Maven2 projects.

Now, I noticed that for a method that returns `List<CustomObj>`, where `CustomObj` has appropriate JAXB annotations, i.e. `@XmlRootElement(name="CustomObj")`, and getter/setters for all relevant members:

- Using **grizzly**, I get something like `{"CustomObj":[{<fields-of-customObj>},{<fields-of-customObj>},{<fields-of-customObj>}]}` (when the list has 3 elements). Parsing this with GSON works fine.
- Using **TomCat**, however, I get this: `[{<fields-of-customObj>},{<fields-of-customObj>},{<fields-of-customObj>}]` -> so as you can see, the "root" is missing somehow

I have the impression that the `jersey-json` module (which I included into my Maven2 dependencies) are not used at all in TomCat, even though they should be used (they are used in Grizzly for sure). Also, creating my own `@Provider` for a `ContextResolver<JAXBContext>` [as described here](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/json.html#json.jaxb.context.resolver.example) only works in grizzly, in TomCat the `getContext()` method will never be called.

Is there anything I need to consider with TomCat?

Cheers!

Comment: did you manage to resolve this problem?

Comment: No. I'm not using this technology anymore either. Sorry.